# Jquery method addClass, removeClass have an issue with fontawesome icon

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I've a fixed position row with fa-angle-double-down.

```
<!-- Intro Section -->
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-fixed">
        <a  class="page-scroll " href="#about">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down hvr-buzz"></i>
        </a>
   </div>
</section>
```

When scroll down, fa-angle-double-down is replaced by fa-angle-double-up, with remove/addClass and so for the href attribute in the a link.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll i").removeClass('fa fa-angle-double-down hvr-buzz');
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll i").addClass('fa fa-angle-double-up hvr-buzz');
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed a").attr("href", "#page-top");
} else {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll i").addClass('fa fa-angle-double-down hvr-buzz');
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll i").removeClass('fa fa-angle-double-up hvr-buzz');
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed a").attr("href", "#about");
}
```

});

Ok, everything works fine, but when go to the top, after one ore more scrolling  down, fa fa-angle-double-down appears, but as a little block, with the same behavior of fa fa-angle-double-down, but not the same appearence.

Why?

Comment: adjust your line height

Comment: can you add more html? or make a jsbin? you can add in FontAwesome in jsbin

Comment: edit this one http://jsbin.com/cexoqakuqi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll i").removeClass();
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll i").addClass('fa fa-angle-double-up hvr-buzz');
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll .fa-angle-double-up").css("color","#000");
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed a").attr("href", "#page-top");
} else {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll i").removeClass();
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll i").addClass('fa fa-angle-double-down hvr-buzz');
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed .page-scroll .fa-angle-double-down").css("color","#FFF");
    $(".intro-section .container .row-fixed a").attr("href", "#about");
}
```

});

Just needed a little patience